Why can't I save the Django FileField with a null value
I want to use a POST request to create an object with file fields.
At the same time, at the model level, I declared that fields can be null.
But Django does not allow me to save this object with empty values in the file fields.
At the same time, through Django admin, I can create an object with without specifying a file.
Error:
ValueError: The 'image_before' attribute has no file associated with it.

What could this be related to?
Request:
{   
    "type": "Type",
    "question": "Text",
    "category": [
        1
    ]
}

My model:
class Question(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'questions'

    question_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=300,
    )

    category = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category,
    )

    question_text = models.CharField(
        max_length=300,
    )

    image_before = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='media/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None,
    )

    correct_answer= models.CharField(
        max_length=300,
        blank=True
    )

I tried to redefine save() and change the value of the field to None there.
Then the value of the field will be <FileField: None>
I have endpoint path('api/v1/create-question/', QuestionCreateAPI.as_view()).
The address by which I want to create model objects.
class QuestionCreateAPI(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        obj, create = create_question(request.data)

        if create:
            return Response(obj, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(obj, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Where create_question:
def create_question(data):
    media_data = data.get('media_data')
    
    if media_data:
       question = Question.objects.create(
                question_type=data['type'],
                question_text=data['question'],
                time_to_answer=data.get('time_to_answer', 0),
                show_image=media_data.get('show_image', False),
                image_before=media_data.get('image', {}).get('before'),
                image_after=media_data.get('image', {}).get('after'),
                video_before=media_data.get('video', {}).get('before'),
                video_after=media_data.get('video', {}).get('after'),
                correct_answer=data['correct_answer'],
                answers=data.get('answers', '')
            )
    else:
        question = Question.objects.create(
                question_type=data['type'],
                question_text=data['question'],
                question_text=data['correct_answer'],
            )
    
    if round_id := data.get('round_id'):
            question.rounds = round_id
    
    return model_to_dict(question), True

I don't use Django templates and Forms.

Please add the html template, view, and if applicable the forms.py.

I have adjusted the question in accordance with your request

This is one of the (very) many reasons to use serializers, and not process user data manually. As they say, you should trust user data, but still check. This is better not done manually.
